# How to change Libraries locations in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to change `MyDocuments`, `MyPhotos` from drive C:\ to D:\

How can I do this on Win7 ?

Do I need to move it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the library, and enter that "folder" you will something that says "Includes: # of locations". If you want to include or remove items, just click on where it says how many things there are. The dialog box that pops up will let you add anything as as long as it is not on a removable device.

If it is on a removable device you are out of luck (In theory, you could edit the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\personal` key in the registry to an arbitrary path, but this is not a good idea, and it could cause many issues if the location is not available for whatever reason, other than not being able to access those files)

Answer (score 2):

For moving the folders completely, you would need to right-click on the folder in your `C:\Users\username` folder, click <kbd>Properties</kbd>, click <kbd>Location</kbd>, click <kbd>Move...</kbd> and choose the new location

Comment: I like this, pretty elegant and correct approach